# HPQC 9.2 compatibility with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4

Tags: quality-center, sql

Does Quality centre 9.2 support Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4.
Hi Friends,

Need your help in understanding compatibility between Quality center 9.2 and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Nivedita Patel

Comment: Try this link: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/QC-9-2-SQL-Server/td-p/5195470 It sounds like it will depend on your patch version, since per that link SQL05 SP3 isn't supported out of the box.

Comment: Hi, Currently we have SQL05 SP3 for HPQC 9.2.We are going to upgrade this to SQL05 Service Pack 4.So please suggest on urgent basis if service pack 4 of SQL05 is supported by HPQC 9.2.